# Sql Result IN a Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, postgresql

dont blame for the database design.I am not its database architect. I am the one who has to use it in current situation

I hope this will be understandable.
I have 3 tables containing following data with no foreign key relationship b/w them:

```
groups
groupId    groupName
1          Admin 
2          Editor
3          Subscriber

preveleges
groupId    roles
1          1,2
2          2,3
3          1

roles
roleId    roleTitle
1         add
2         edit
```

Query:

```
SELECT roles 
from groups
LEFT JOIN preveleges ON (groups.groupId=preveleges.groupId)
```

returns specific result i.e roles.

Problem: I wanted to show **roleTitle** instead of **roles** in the above query.
I am confused how to relate table roles with this query and returns required result

I know it is feasible with coding but i want in SQL.Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You should change your DB structure. Don't store multiple values in one column. It will only give you headaches.

Comment: @juergend i appreciate your suggestion.Still there will be a way to sort it out

Comment: There's a good way to sort it out, and a bad way. juergen's suggestion is the Good Way -- I suspect that you're looking for the Bad Way.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  hey David, i have a large set of records already arranged in this pattern, this is just a scenario. I am struck, looking for a solution

Comment: Are you interested in a programatic way of modifying that table to a correct structure, and of migrating the data without having to re-enter it?

Comment: @DavidAldridge instead of it, i would rather use code logic to retrieve and show data

Comment: Databases are made for specific purpose, and if you use it correctly (and correctly in this context means *the only possible way*) then you won't have problems. You haven't used the database correctly - you stored multiple values in 1 column instead of creating a row for every entry - and therefore you're looking for, what @DavidAldridge labeled - the Bad Way. Sadly, people looking for Bad Way solutions shouldn't be in the position to do so in the first place. I suggest listening to smart people here and change your structure. You'll be grateful later. But if you want the bad way - good luck.

Comment: @N.B. I agree with you whenever it is possible. But sometimes real life restrictions prevent you from doing thing properly. For example: What if the database you are working with is managed by a different company and they refuse to change the structure? In that case we have no choice but to look for a bad solution.

Comment: @NLwino - I'm sorry but this is a straightforward case, inventing cases where you can't do something is easy, that doesn't mean that it should be used as an excuse. Also, I work with a company which employs  sub-par programmers who often use bad approaches or database structures. And guess what - every time something is designed wrong gets rejected by us. Designing **simple** things wrong and blaming it on "real world" scenario is just a bad excuse to cover up for laziness and lack of knowledge and as such it must be treated harshly.

Comment: @NLwino Agree, this is literally RDBMS 101 -- failure to meet First Normal Form. Pragmatically speaking, you can get away with it in some circumstances, such as where the data might naturally be represented as an array, but not in a key column that you are joining on.

Comment: @N.B. I wish I invented the example case, unfortunately it was something out of my own experience. I had to come up with solutions for problems on a database that I wasn't allowed to change. Made sure they knew their design sucked though :P

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT g.groupName,
       GROUP_CONCAT(r.roleTitle 
                    ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(r.roleId, p.roles))
         AS RoleTitles
FROM groups AS g
  LEFT JOIN preveleges AS p 
    ON g.groupId = p.groupId
  LEFT JOIN roles AS r
    ON FIND_IN_SET(r.roleId, p.roles)
GROUP BY g.groupName ;
```

Tested at: **[SQL-FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa555/6)**

Answer (score 2):

I would change the data structure it self. Since It's not normalised, there are multiple elements in a single column.

But it is possible with SQL, if for some (valid) reason you can't change the DB.

A simple "static" solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(roles, '1', 'add'), '2', 'edit') from groups
LEFT JOIN preveleges ON(groups.groupId=preveleges.groupId)
```

A more complex but still ugly solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ReplaceRoleIDWithName (@StringIds VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @RoleNames VARCHAR(50)
    SET @RoleNames = @StringIds
    SELECT @RoleNames = REPLACE(@RoleNames, CAST(RoleId AS VARCHAR(50)), roleTitle)
    FROM roles
    RETURN @RoleNames
END
```

And then use the function in the query

```
SELECT ReplaceRoleIDWithName(roles) from groups
LEFT JOIN preveleges ON(groups.groupId=preveleges.groupId)
```

It is possible without function, but this is more readable. Made without editor so it's not tested in anyway.

Comment: i have a large set of records already arranged in this pattern, this is just a scenario. i think this will not help

Comment: @CodePlayer Have added a more complex solution.

Answer (score 2):

You also tagged the question with PostgreSQL and it's actually quite easy with Postgres to work around this broken design:

```
SELECT grp.groupname, r.roletitle 
FROM groups grp
  join (
    select groupid, cast(regexp_split_to_table(roles, ',') as integer) as role_id
    from privileges
  ) as privs on privs.groupid = grp.groupid
  join roles r on r.roleid = privs.role_id;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5e87b/1

(Note that I changed the incorrectly spelled name `preveleges` to the correct spelling `privileges`)

But you should really, *really* re-design your data model!

Fixing your design also enables you to define foreign key constraints and validate the input. In your current model, the application would probably break (just as my query would), if someone inserted the value `'one,two,three'` into the roles table.

**Edit**

To complete the picture, using Postgres's array handling the above could be slightly simplified using a similar approach as MySQL's `find_in_set()`

```
select grp.groupname, r.roletitle 
from groups grp
  join privileges privs on grp.groupid = privs.groupid 
  join roles r on r.roleid::text = any (string_to_array(privs.roles, ','))
```

In both cases if all role titles should be shown as a comma separated list, the string_agg() function could be used (which is equivalent to MySQL's `group_concat()`

```
select grp.groupname, string_agg(r.roletitle, ',')
from groups grp
  join privileges privs on grp.groupid = privs.groupid 
  join roles r on r.roleid::text = any (string_to_array(privs.roles, ','))
group by grp.groupname
```

Comment: @CodePlayer: suit yourself. But I'd bet you'll spend much more time fixing your data and fighting this problem then it would take to implement the correct design.

Comment: Actually, there is [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function which can solve the OP's problem (in a Bad way, no argues there). The best would be to change the design.

Comment: well  FIND_IN_SET() works for me..ofcourse not a good approach..still thanx both

Comment: @ypercube: indeed, `find_in_set()` is a nice trick. You can do something similar with Postgres as well.